# PowerBI - DAX - Removing Duplicates and Returning YES after comparing 2 columns based on a condition

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Hi I have the table(EmpDetailsail) with below details.

**SOID  |  VDM_Name**

AA001 | DS3001

AA002 | DS3002

AA001 | DS3007

AA002 | DS3002

Here, I have SOID (AA001) which has access to 2 VDM's (DS3001 & DS3007) Also, AA002 which is a duplicate entry in the table.

1. I would like to delete the duplicate entries (like removing one entry of AA002 from the table).
2. After removing duplicates, I would want to create a column "Access" which shows "YES" if the SOID's has access to more than 1 VDM's.

**SOID  |  VDM_Name | Access**

AA001 | DS3001 | YES

AA002 | DS3002 | NO

AA001 | DS3007 | YES

how could I achieve this using DAX or M query ? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DAX`

```
_tbl =
SELECTCOLUMNS (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                'Table',
                "allRank",
                    MAXX (
                        FILTER ( 'Table', [SOID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[SOID] ) ),
                        RANKX (
                            FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[SOID] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[SOID] ) ),
                            'Table'[VDM],
                            ,
                            ASC,
                            DENSE
                        )
                    )
            ),
            [SOID],
            [VDM],
            [allRank]
        ),
        "Access", IF ( [allRank] > 1, "Yes", "No" )
    ),
    "SOID", [SOID],
    "VDM", [VDM],
    "Access", [Access]
)
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

First remove duplicates in power query

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\Data_20oct21.xlsx"), null, true),
    Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"SOID ", type text}, {" VDM_Name", type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Changed Type1")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Then write a dax to achieve the result

[image]

Comment: If this answer is useful to you, accept the answer